# Inverting a matrix using Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices, schur-complement

> Show that if $B\in \mathbb{C}^{p\times q}$ and $C\in \mathbb{C}^{q\times  p}$, then $I_p -BC$ is invertible $\Longleftrightarrow I_q-CB$ is invertible.

Specifically, use the Schur complement:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I_p-BC & B\\
C & I_q-CB
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p & O \\
C(I_p-BC)^{-1} & I_q
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p-BC & O \\
O & (I_q-CB)-C(I_p-BC)^{-1}B\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p & (I_p-BC)^{-1}B \\
O & I_q\end{bmatrix}$$

I believe the best way to go about solving this problem is to prove the term $(I_q-CB)-C(I_p-BC)^{-1}B$ is invertible, because we know the first and third matrices in our Schur decomposition are invertible (the diagonal elements are nonzero, and they are block triangular) and the $I_p-BC$ term is invertible by assumption.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could just check that if $X$ is the inverse of $I_p-BC$ then $Y=I_q+CXB$ is the inverse of $I_q-CB$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument that uses Schur complements (though note that it seems it is not common to refer to the factorization in the OP as a "Schur decomposition", which term refers to a different factorization; in my opinion it is better to refer to the factorization in question something along the lines of "block bireduction (aka both row and column reduction)").

---

First let's set up some notation. For

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix} $$

a block matrix, if any one of the blocks is invertible (and in particular square), then there are two invertible matrices $L$ and $R$ such that

$$M = L \begin{pmatrix}
\blacksquare & 0 \\
0 & M/\blacksquare 
\end{pmatrix} R,$$

where $\blacksquare$ is the invertible block and $M/\blacksquare$ is by definition its **Schur complement**.

In particular if $A$ is invertible, then $M/A = D  - CA^{-1}B$ and similarly if $D$ is invertible, then $M/D = A-BD^{-1}C$. This same factorization also gives the following:

**Observation:** If $\blacksquare$ is invertible, then $M$ is invertible iff $M/\blacksquare$ is invertible.

Using the observation note that, putting $A = I_p$ and $D = I_q$, one has

$$M/I_p = I_q - CB, \quad M/I_q = I_p - BC.$$

As identity matrices are invertible, $I_q-CB$ is invertible iff $M$ is invertible iff $I_p-BC$ is invertible.